# Why do I have low voltage,(107-110VAC) and nothing will power on one circuit?

Tags: electrical

I started this project for a home we were remodeling to flip and have never been able to get a solid answer as to why this happened

I have to be rather long winded to fully explain so I apologize.

I was rewiring the basement in this home and had successfully completed the entire project and got down to one last circuit that was nearest the box but the feeder came from behind a concrete wall and I’m not sure what happened to the line between this point and the main load center.

Everything in the LC was wired correctly but there was four outlets down stream that were showing roughly 107-110 volts on my meter. But they wouldn’t power anything at all.

I figured this out because after wiring it, I had just checked it with my multimeter but before the Inspection I was going to plug up a box fan to get some musty air out of the basement and it Wouldn’t work.

I fought it that evening, never coming to a conclusion other than just completely rewiring  the entire circuit but I never have spoke to anyone That could give me a clue as to why it happened or what could possibly have been going on.

I know that the 107-110 volts was low for that circuit as all other circuits in

Comment: Putting a question in the title and adding some formatting would help the wall of text become readable.

Comment: Adding some pics of the junction boxes in question would probably help.

Comment: I would check the voltage with a load it may have been phantom voltage with the root cause an open breaker or bad connection on that line.

Comment: You'll probably want to [edit] this further. Note that you have to put in a completely blank line to get a new paragraph on this system. Obviously the end isn't complete.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you have a bad connection or broken wire causing a high resistance.  The voltage drop will be Current x Resistance.  The multimeter has a very high input impedance (resistance), so the voltage will be only slightly low (I'm assuming this should be 120V).  A load will draw more current which will cause the voltage to drop to a much lower value.

Comment: Spot on - somewhere in "*came from behind a concrete wall and I’m not sure what happened to the line between this point and the main load center.*" there was a bad connection - odds are that if you had checked the voltage **while** trying to run your fan, it would have been 0-5 volts. Completely rewiring the circuit (or at least the part from the panel to that point) was exactly the right thing to do, unless you could find a junction box along the way to check.